# Apache hive: Compare data between 2 tables and generate a report

Tags: linux, hive

I have 2 tables with similiar schema in the same cluster.
I want to compare the data between both the tables and generate a report. Is it possible only within hql?
Do you suggest any better approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Add data samples including requested results

Comment: Yes you can. But give me some examples.

Comment: I am using an UDF to compare all the field values between 2 tables. @PadmanabhanVijay, 
example:
tbl1: string field1, string field2, string field3
tbl2: string fieldA, string fieldB, string fieldC

select field1, field2, field3, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, compareUDF(field1, field2, field3, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC) as comment

Comment: I am using an UDF to compare all the field values between 2 tables. @PadmanabhanVijay, 
example:
tbl1: string field1, string field2, string field3
tbl2: string fieldA, string fieldB, string fieldC

create temprary function compareUDF as '';
select field1, field2, field3, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, compareUDF(field1, field2, field3, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC) as comment from tbl1, tbl2.

Compare will have the mismatch field names.

How can I pass the 2 table fields as map? Hope this helps

Comment: I worked on similar task.. I will share you the code snippet. Give me some time..keep looking this thread. will update the answer. No need of UDF.. We can do it using map function..

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this Python program that handles such comparisons of Hive tables (comparing all the rows and all the columns), and would show you in a webpage the differences that might appear: https://github.com/bolcom/hive_compared_bq

It doesn't currently give you a "full report" but it will instead just pinpoint some of the differences found (the tool is more intended in a development cycle, to check if code is correct) but I guess you could extend the final part of the program for that.

Comment: Thank you Sourygna. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Have you been able to give it a try Aavik?